# Create an object array from another object array and reconstruct the original object array later using map

Tags: arrays, swift

Consider the following classes

```
class Category {
       var tag: String?
       var itemList: [Item]?
 }

 class Item {
       var id: Int?
       var type: String?
       var itemDetails: ItemDetails?  
 }

 class ItemDetails {
       var description: String?
       var name: String?
       var price: Float?
 }
```

Given an array of **Category** objects.

```
var categoryList: [Category]
```

I want to create a new object array by extracting only the **name** in **ItemDetails**(inorder to apply a filter) and an **id** inorder to reconstruct back array of Category objects.

Hence, I have to reconstruct the array of **Category** objects
from new object array.

How to do both extraction and reconstruction using the `map` feature?

Below are the examples of other data sources:

**Datasource 1 :**

`var categoryList: [Category]`, where `name` need to be extracted

**Datasource 2 :**

`var  searchList = [SearchItem]`, where title to be extracted.

```
    Class SearchItem {
         var id: Int?
         var details: SearchItemDetails?
         var type: String? 
    }

    Class  SearchItemDetails {               
        var description: String?
        var title: String? 
    }
```

**DataSource 3**

`var products:  [Products]`, where title to be extracted.

```
    Class Products {
        var id: Int?
        var details: ProductDetails?
        var type: String? 
    }

    class ProductDetails {
        var description: String?
        var title: String? 
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just filter current categories? What is the need of *reconstruction*?

Comment: Actually, I have some pages with different data source. So I'am trying to create a utility class with one method to do filtering for all pages. Hence, I need to extract common datasource and reconstruct original to render results in corresponding pages.

Comment: So you need different filters. Can you show me an example of different datasources?

Comment: But the requirement is to use only one filter function.  Hence, I need to construct a new datasource with item to be filtered(strings only)  for every page. To reconstruct original, new datasource should contain filtering item and an id.   `categoryList` in the question is an example of one such data source.

Comment: No I mean *different examples* so I can investigate more for a good mapping function

Comment: I have edited the question with few examples

Comment: You should use protocols to achieve that. Are you familiar with that ?

Comment: Yes. But I'am confused with how to do extraction and reconstruction in Datasource 1.

Answer (score 1):

To get an array of just the names, you do the `map` like you mentioned:

```swift
let categories: [Category] = ... // this already exists
let itemNames = categories.map { $0.itemList?.map({ $0.itemDetails?.name }) }
```

But this will preserve optionals. If you don't want optionals, then use `compactMap` instead.

Reconstructing, however, doesn't really make any sense. Are you using the ID to hit a database or network service? That's the only possible way you'd be able to reconstruct the original array of `Category`s. Why not just hold onto the original array?

Comment: Actually, I have some pages with different data source. So I'am trying to create a utility class with one method to do filtering for all pages. Hence, I need to extract common datasource and reconstruct original to render results in corresponding pages.